# Jquery Treeview Plugin Location persistance

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview, location

Love the JQuery Treewiev plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/ , but I have one problem with it.

I am using location based persistence, but if there is a get variable in the url it doesn't persist correctly.

For example:
htp://yourwebpage.com/group

is recognized differently than
htp://yourwebpage.com/group?group_id=555

I understand why there might be cases that they shouldn't match, but is there a way to get treeView to match these two states. So how can I fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the way of accessing location in the jquery.treeview.js

```
var current = this.find("a").filter(function() {
  return this.href.toLowerCase() == location.href.toLowerCase();
});
```

to

```
var current = this.find("a").filter(function() {
  return this.href.toLowerCase() == location.href.toLowerCase().split("?")[0];
});
```

or use cookie persistence and set the cookie value to `location.href.toLowerCase().split("?")[0]`